# Styling my section/chapter

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

I'm trying to reproduce this chapter/section style on LaTeX and I would like some insight on how to achieve this. I have been using the `secsty` package but I haven't come up with any real results.

The idea is for this to represent a chapter in my document but I suppose there's no problem in calling this a section and my original sections subsections.[image]

Thanks,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please don't ask "How do I achieve this layout", but rather a question about a specific feature that you're struggling with, one problem per question. This way other users who have a similar problem can benefit from your question and the solutions to it (No one's gonna ask for the same layout as you). It's no problem to ask several questions, if you've made some attempt yourself first. It's enormously helpful to see what you've tried so far to figure out what doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; a little example that you can take as starting point:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\scshape\Huge}
  {\hspace*{-70pt}\thechapter.~#1}
  {-15pt}
  {\hspace*{-110pt}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+80pt\relax}{3pt}\Huge}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\scshape\Huge}
  {\hspace*{-70pt}#1}
  {-15pt}
  {\hspace*{-110pt}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+80pt\relax}{3pt}\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And a little modification (requested in a comment) allowing you to change the color for the rules using the features provided by the `xcolor` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text

%\colorlet{myrulecolor}{black}
\definecolor{myrulecolor}{RGB}{150,20,0}% define the color for the rules

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\scshape\Huge}
  {\hspace*{-70pt}\thechapter.~#1}
  {-15pt}
  {\hspace*{-110pt}{\color{myrulecolor}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+80pt\relax}{3pt}}\Huge}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\scshape\Huge}
  {\hspace*{-70pt}#1}
  {-15pt}
  {\hspace*{-110pt}{\color{myrulecolor}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+80pt\relax}{3pt}}\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly this. One more question: is it possible to apply the same style to the table of contents header? as in http://imgur.com/bAE8G

Comment: @seth: To modify the appearance of the table of contents, you should check out the `toxloft` package.

Comment: @seth: sure; I've added the necessary code to my answer.

Comment: Can i change the color of these lines? (the underlining i mean)

Comment: @seth: yes, you can; see my updated answer.

Comment: How would you recommend to deal with long titles?