# Formatting chapter in memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, rules

I'm trying to reproduce this chapter heading ([Styling my section/chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48130/styling-my-section-chapter)) in `memoir`. This is more or less working with the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makechapterstyle{uno}{%
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{5pt}
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}%
  \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
   \hspace*{-0.1\textwidth}\chaptitlefont ##1}
  \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{%
   \vskip -2pt \hspace*{-\marginparwidth}\rule{0.7\textwidth}{5pt}}
   }

 \chapterstyle{uno}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Es war einmal ein Mann}
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

But my question: Why does the following code:

```
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{%
\vskip\midchapskip\hspace*{-\marginparwidth}\rule{0.7\textwidth}{5pt}}
}
```

leave such a large separation to the rule? As far as I understand, `\vskip` is creating a new paragraph. But if I use

```
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{%
\vskip\midchapskip\hrule}
}
```

there is no separation at all (only the `5pt` of `\midchapskip`). `\rule` and `\hrule` are behaving differently, but I can not understand why and I did not see a good explanation for this.

Answer (score 6):

`\hrule` is a vertical mode command so in vertical mode stacks directly under the previous thing.

The LaTeX `\rule` starts with `\leavevmode` and so is a horizontal mode command and so if used in vertical mode you will get a vertical `\parskip` space and a horizontal `\parindent`.

You will see the same behaviour if you compare `\hbox{hello}` with `\mbox[hello}`

(Also in your example you have `\hspace*` in the `\rule` example which similarly is a horizontal command.)

Perhaps this is closer to your needs

```
 \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{{%
   \par\offinterlineskip\hbox{\hspace*{-\marginparwidth}\rule{0.7\textwidth}{5pt}}}}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I'm reading right now doc about the two TEX modes in order to understand it. Where can I see the definition of `\rule`?